# $G$ be a non-measurable subgroup of $(\mathbb R,+)$ ; $I$ be a bounded interval , then $m^*(G \cap I)=m^*(I)$?

Tags: real-analysis, group-theory, measure-theory, outer-measure

Let $G$ be a non-measurable subgroup of $(\mathbb R,+)$ , $I$ be a bounded interval , then is it true that $m^*(G \cap I)=m^*(I)(=|I|)$ ? where $m^*$ denotes the Lebesgue outer measure

Comment: Note that $G$ is dense, since it cannot be countable.

Comment: @LeGrandDODOM : yeah I can see that $G$ is dense and uncountable ... but does that help much ?

Comment: Do you know if this is true for hyperplanes of $\mathbf R$ ? (viewed as a $\mathbf Q $-vector space)

Comment: This one seems to be related: https://www.jstor.org/stable/2325061?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer "yes" follows from results in the article "On Two Halves Being Two Wholes" by Andrew Simoson in *The American Mathematical Monthly* Vol. 91, No. 3 (Mar., 1984), pp. 190-193.  Some readers might not have access, but here is the JSTOR link: http://www.jstor.org/stable/2322357 The article was cited in the [article](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2325061?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents) [i707107](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/67070/i707107) linked to in [a comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2101953/g-be-a-non-measurable-subgroup-of-mathbb-r-i-be-a-bounded-interval#comment4348049_2101953).

In the article a subset $A\subseteq \mathbb R$ is called *Archimedean* if $\{r\in\mathbb R:A+r=A\}$ is dense in $\mathbb R$.  Theorem 2 states that if $A$ is Archimedean with positive outer measure, then for every interval $I$, $m^*(A\cap I)=m^*(I)$.

A dense subgroup of $\mathbb R$ is Archimedean, and a nonmeasurable subgroup of $\mathbb R$ is dense with positive outer measure, so the theorem applies to affirm your conjecture.

Answer (score 3):

From the article provided by @Jonas Meyer: http://www.jstor.org/stable/2322357

An alternative approach to this problem is possible. This approach is already provided by @Syang Chen at MathOverflow: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/59978/additive-subgroups-of-the-reals/59980

Let $f(x) = m^*(G\cap [0,x])$. Then, for any $x, y \in G \cap (0,\infty)$, we have the additivity:
$$
f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y).
$$
Since $G$ is dense and $f$ is monotone, the additivity is generalized to all positive real numbers $x, y$. Moreover, $f(x) = ax$ with $a= f(1)$ is satisfied.

Thus, if $I$ is any open interval, then 
$$
\frac{m^*(G\cap I)}{m^*(I)} = a .
$$

Now, we find $I$ by the Theorem 1 in the article. This gives $a=1$.

Comment: There is (at least) one other interesting answer on that MO question, apparently for every $a\in(0;1)$ there is a non measurable subgroup of $\mathbf R$ with Hausdorf dimension $a$.